# Undefined Control Sequence in \multido or \pspicture?

Tags: pstricks, syntax, animations, multido

I wrote the following very simple program as I'm trying to make an animation using pstricks and multido, but I get "undefined control sequence" on the end pspicture line. Can anyone just tell me what's wrong with my code? I've been trying for a few hours to read documentation on multido and the pspicture environment. I can't see where I've used any wrong syntax.

```
% growingCircle.tex
% xelatex growingCircle
% convert -delay 4 -loop 0 -density 200 -alpha remove growingCircle.pdf growingCircle.gif

\documentclass[border=0pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand\FPS{25} %25 frames per second

\newcommand\Period{5} %Length of clip

\newcommand\TotalFrames{\FPS*\Period}

\begin{document}

\multido{\n=0.00+0.01}{\TotalFrames}{
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle{\n}
  \end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to the very first line of your document and compile again, type in `s` and type enter when the error prompt flashes. Please show the resulting `log` file.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as you said pdflatex I realized my error. I was using TeXWorks and the compile button was indeed calling pdflatex. I went to the command line (like my own comment to myself says!) and it worked. Well, another error, it didn't like my \FPS*\Period. It would make the first page have '*5' and then just 25 more pages. I got rid of those two newcommands and put a straight 120 (multiple of 24, the frames per second convert called for) and then it made a nice 120 page (5-second) pdf.

Comment: @Pete: I think you don't need to have `pstricks` as an optional argument to the standalone class, since you load `pstricks-add`, whch loads pstricks and a few other members of the pstricks family. Note you *can*  compile with `pdflaatex`: all you have to do is loading `auto-pst-pdf` and use the `--shell-escape` switch for the compiler, or `--enable-write18` if you're with MiKTeX.